# How to count the number of words in a text file using c

Tags: c, file-handling

I know the approach where we count the number of spaces and '\n', but take for example the content of file is `"This    is   Aakshat"` (it has multiple spaces b/w words), then how would you count the number of words, in this case counting the number of spaces will not give the answer.

Comment: You keep track of whether you are in a word or not.  If you're in a word and read a space, you've reached the end of a word.  If you're in a word a read a non-space, you're still in the same word.  If you're not in a word and read a space, you ignore it.  If you're not in a word and read a non-space, you start a new word.  At some point, you count the new word — it's best to do that when you transition to being in a word.  You're not in a word when the processing starts.

Comment: You should be showing us what you've tried and explaining where you're having problems.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages.

Comment: What reads whitespace separated words in C? Ah, `scanf()` with a `"%s"` format specifier fits the bill. Don't forget to use the *field-width* modifier as 1-less than your buffer size to avoid writing beyond the end of your array.

Comment: Don't count whitespace.  Instead, count transitions.

Answer (score 0):

To count the number of words in a byte stream, you should count the number of transitions from whitespace to non-whitespace, starting in whitespace state.

Here is a simple implementation:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int inspace = 1;
    int count = 0;
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (isspace(c)) {
            inspace = 1;
        } else {
            count += inspace;
            inspace = 0;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```